# Is there a way to change the background of an image with js after a ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a page that creates a 36 page book with php, ant then shows it to the user using a flipbook.js. Since the book is so big, the page takes a long time to load (something like 15 seconds), so I thought make the page create only 5 book pages, and then creating the rest using ajax so that the user doesn't wait too much. The problem is that when i create the other pages and i try to change the background using jquery on the ajax.success function the page doesn't show the images.

If i do this with normal images using the src instead of the background it works.

Can anybody help me find a way?

thanks.

Comment: share your code if you really need solutions or suggestion

Comment: Did you tried : `$("#your_element").css("background", "url('the_new_background_url')")` ?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just add the normal images by jquery on ajax success if that's been working for you?

a simple idea of how to add src to an image would be:

```
$('image_selector').attr('src', $src);
```

Makes sense?